# return a pointer to a block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a static block variable inside a class. How can I declare a property or an instance selector to return or send that block to a caller?

This is my static block:

```
static NSResultComparison(^myBlock)(id obj1, id obj2);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? What's the problem with just declaring your property/method to have the block as a return type? Or do you not know the syntax for that? The unnamed form of your block type is `(NSResultComparison (^)(id, id))`.

Comment: @KevinBallard I agree clarification is needed. I have updated my answer to show the scenario of a static block variable for the class being returned for all calls to the selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be best to `typedef` your block.

```
//interface.h
typedef NSResultComparison (^ComparisonBlock)(id obj1, id obj2);

@interface ...
...

-(ComparisonBlock) getComparisonBlock;

@end
```

---

```
//implementation.m
//Here is your static block implementation
static ComparisonBlock myStaticBlock = ^(id obj1, id obj2)
{
    ...
    return result;
};

@implementation ...

-(ComparisonBlock)getComparisonBlock
{
    return myStaticBlock;
}

@end
```

Comment: That's useful if the block type is going to be used multiple times, but I'm not sure that's actually what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Not necessarily. Most of the times I have custom blocks in properties or methods, I don't bother with a typedef because the block signature is only going to be typed once or twice. Typedefs pollute the global type namespace, and there's really no point for once-off blocks.

Comment: Thanks, the typedef did it for me.. I was trying to declare something like +(^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)) getComparisonBlock but it would not take it. With the typedef it does

Comment: Just for the record, your method signature would have worked with this: `+(NSComparisonResult(^)(id, id))getComparisonBlock`.